# Saving sockaddr from getaddrinfo to sockaddr_storage

Tags: c, network-programming

I'm trying to write an IPv4/IPv6 agnostic program with C. The 3rd argument of `getaddrinfo` is set with `AF_UNSPEC`, so the result might be IPv4 or IPv6. I'd like to save the result to `struct sockaddr_storage` so that I can reuse it later. Here's what I'm doing:

```
static int init_server(const char *hostname, const char *proto, const char *port, struct sockaddr_storage *serv_addr)
{
    struct addrinfo *addr;
    struct addrinfo hints;
    int rc;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));

    if (!strcmp(proto, "tcp")) {
        hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    } else if (!strcmp(proto, "udp")) {
        hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }

    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    rc = getaddrinfo(hostname, port, &hints, &addr);
    if (rc != 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    memset(serv_addr, 0, sizeof(*serv_addr));
    memcpy(serv_addr, addr->ai_addr, addr->ai_addrlen);

    freeaddrinfo(addr);

    return 0;
}
```

Am I copying the result correctly? I find C socket related structs confusing so this might be a total nonsense.

Comment: Note that serv_addr is a pointer, so sizeof(serv_addr) will yield 4 or 8. This is not what you want.

Comment: @BjornA. Thanks, I've fixed it.

Comment: Be aware that `getaddrinfo()` might return several "chained" `struct addrinfo`. The code shown just takes care of the 1st.

Comment: @alk is it important to check the remaining structs?

Comment: This depends on your needs, which we do not know. The 1st `struct` for example might just be returning `localhost`/`127.0.0.1` for example.